# Import modules in one place for better organisation and remove duplicate import statements

Tags: javascript, module

I have following dir structure

```
app
├── default.js
├── index.html
├── ObserverPattern
    ├── ConcreteObserver.mjs
    ├── ConcreteSubject.mjs
    ├── ObserverList.mjs
    ├── Observer.mjs
    └── Subject.mjs
```

In `index.html`  I have `<script type="module" src="default.js"></script>`

In `default.js` I have following code

```js
import { Observer } from "./ObserverPattern/Observer.mjs";
import { ObserverList } from "./ObserverPattern/ObserverList.mjs";
import { Subject } from "./ObserverPattern/Subject.mjs";
import { ConcreteObserver } from "./ObserverPattern/ConcreteObserver.mjs";
import { ConcreteSubject } from "./ObserverPattern/ConcreteSubject.mjs";
```

In `ConcreteObserver.mjs`  I have following code

```js
class ConcreteObserver extends Observer {
  constructor(element) {
    super();
    this.element = element;
  }

  update(value) {
    this.element.checked = value;
  }

}

export {
  ConcreteObserver
};
```

When I run via local web server, I get error that `Uncaught ReferenceError: Observer is not defined`

If I then add `import { Observer } from './Observer.mjs';` at top of `ConcreteObserver.mjs` then it works without error.

Is there a way to import all the modules in `default.js` so that I don't have to include `import { Observer } from './Observer.mjs';` in every Concrete implementation?

Something like php composer `autoload`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good part of the point of modules is to isolate code so you don't end up with vast numbers of in-scope variables which aren't being used.

Since you seem to be running in a browser you *could* explicitly assigned values to the global object…

```
import { Observer } from "./ObserverPattern/Observer.mjs";
window.Observer = Observer;
```

And then use `window.Observer` elsewhere.

But that makes code hard to manage. Linters won't be able to catch errors where you failed to assign the variable properly. You risk race conditions where you try to read the value before you assign to the window object.

If you need to use `Observer` then import it where you need to use it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll only import where it is needed. I was hoping something like php `composer` exists where I don't have to manually import the file. I also realised that import is more like php's `use` statement  rather than like php `require` or `include`

Answer (score 1):

One of the points of modules is that they're self-contained and the relationships between them are explicitly, statically defined (primarily; there is a dynamic form of import). There is no automatic import in ESM.

For your `ConcreteObserver` implementation to work as-is, `Observer` would have to be a global, and would have to be defined before `ConcreteObserver` is evaluated. That is something you could do, though my view is you shouldn't, by making `Observer.mjs` assign `Observer` to a property on `globalThis` (in modern environments, `global` on older Node.js or `window` in older browsers). But other than that, you're going to need at least one `import` in `ConcreteObserver.mjs`.

There are a couple of things you can do to keep the number of distinct `import` statements down, if that's a goal. For instance, you can group things together a bit more (`Observer`, `ObserverList`, and `Subject` all seem closely-related, so they might all go in a single module). But you'd still need that `import` in `ConcreteObserver.mjs`. It's also possible for one module to re-export things from other modules (for example: `export { Something } from "./somewhere.mjs";`), if you wanted to have a master module for all the `ObserverPattern` stuff that exported everything defined in the files that make it up. But again, you'd still need `import` in `ConcreteObserver.mjs`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into grouping and re-exporting but it seems like they are also going to add another layer of complexity. For now I'll use `import` where it is needed.

Comment: @codescope - Yeah, that's usually best. :-)